# How to start abstract of previous research activities for a PhD position

Tags: phd, research-process, writing, statement-of-purpose

I know that's a very simple question but I just don't know how to start it? What will be the introductory paragraph? I am applying for a Ph.D. position related to my field and luckily I am fulfilling all the requirements for the program. I have relevant research experience and publication for the position. Long story short, I just don't want to lose this opportunity.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Kindly read this "In the course of the application process, you will be asked to upload an abstract of your previous research activities (max. 1500 characters), a curriculum vitae, and a collection of relevant certificates".

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink things here. I recommend something like the following:

> I began my research in this field by investigating *bla bla bla* (refs).  discovered that *bla bla bla* (refs), leading to our research on *bla bla bla* (refs). At this point, I was awarded a research grant with Dr. Bob to investigate *bla bla bla*  (grant ref), and we discovered that *bla bla bla* (refs).

Concise and full of as many refs as you can cram in. If you won any grant awards, mention it, unless you're out of space, in which case get rid of some of the other text and mention it. Short and sweet is key here.